# Why Google charged me twice for Android Developer Registration Fee?

Tags: android, google-play

I've a problem with my Android Developer account, my registration is success but instead paid 25$, Google charged me 25$ again, total is 50$.

My Developer account register success on Mar 3 and I can publish my app. But I not logged on to it until May 14, when Android Market change name to "Google Play Market", On May 14 I logged on and problem is occurred, Google charge me 25 USD again!

This is my order history in my Google Wallet:

*Mar 3: You placed an order with Google on Mar 3. Google Checkout sent a copy of this receipt to xxx*

*Mar 3: Google received your order. //==> Charged me 25$, registration success*

*May 14: Google charged your VISA xxx for $25.00. Google Play" will appear on your billing statement. // ==> Charged me 25$ again, when I logged in to my Google Play Account!*

And now I don't know why and cannot found the way to contact Google support

Thank you (and sorry for my English).

Comment: Same problem here. 3 years later

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They shouldn't charge you twice. I heard it happened to others as well. You need to file a complaint:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/request.py?contact_type=dev_registration

Comment: I have the same problem but when i want to apply i cannot detect my transaction Id in pay.google.com .. and without the transaction Id cannot submit for the support. Any advice?